# Adding a fadeOut to an image in with C# in a windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, windows-store-apps

I write a windows store app with C# and XAML and I try to add a fadeOut animation to an image.

If i add the animation in XAML Code like this, it works and I can start the animation with 'RemoveMatchsticks.Begin();' in C#

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Matches" Height="200">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="RemoveMatchsticks">
            <FadeOutThemeAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="matchstick" />
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Image Source="Assets/Match.png" x:Name="matchstick" />
</StackPanel>
```

But I need to add an animation in C#. For testing I have the same picture in XAML

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Matches" Height="200">
    <Image Source="Assets/Match.png" x:Name="matchstick" />
</StackPanel>
```

and the following c#-Code

```
Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
FadeOutThemeAnimation fadeOut = new FadeOutThemeAnimation();
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
fadeOut.Duration = duration;
storyboard.Duration = duration;

Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOut, "Opacity");
Storyboard.SetTarget(fadeOut, matchstick);
storyboard.Begin();
```

It doesn't work. I think, the targetProperty in SetTargetProperty is wrong, but I don't know the correct way and there aren't any error messages.

Thanks,
Klaus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't added the animation to the `Storyboard`. You need to:

```
storyboard.Children.Add(fadeOut);
```

Also, to clean up your code a bit, the `FadeOutThemeAnimation` is [described on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.fadeoutthemeanimation.aspx):

> Represents the preconfigured opacity animation that applies to
>   controls when they are removed from the UI or hidden.

You can remove the `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty`. The animation handles the correct properties for you. You didn't set it in XAML either, so to recreate it in C#, you don't set it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The missing line was the problem. I added the missing line and removed `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty` and now it works. Thanks